# HTML form hide text in S3 POST browser uploader

Tags: html, forms, text, post, amazon-s3

I am building an S3 POST browser uploader. I have to use HTML as I will also be hosting the site on S3 which will presently only host HTML sites.

I have the uploader working fine however I am stumped when it comes to hiding the text pre entered into the form.

Image of the uploader

[image: http://goo.gl/zDv60]

I am using HTML

```
         input type="text" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}"
```

I am sure this is a simple fix however I have either forgotten or never knew how to do it.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to hide that text field? If so, this should do it (replacing type 'text' with 'hidden'):

```
input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}"
```

Comment: Doh. Just noticed how old this was. My bad.